# What was the looping program?

Tags: music, looping, live-performance

A couple of years ago I saw an artist at a music festival using a piece of software to create a loop/sample/synth piece of music. The software had a black and white user interface, with blocks representing different loops. One of the distinctive characteristics of the interface was that each block had a progress bar that moved across the block as the loop played back, and it appeared to me that the blocks had different lengths, and could be synchronous or asynchronous.

What was that piece of software?

Comment: Do you recall any other details? There are a lot of looping programs out there ([here's one list I found](http://www.krispenhartung.com/software-looping.htm)). The most famous of these is Ableton Live - and if your question is really "I want to use software like this," that's a pretty good contender - but doesn't have its progress bars over the blocks themselves.

Comment: What year was it and pc / mac?

Comment: I think it was actually a linux program, and the year was 2012.

Comment: Unless you van recall the actual artist, this will be hard to answer.. 'everyone' is making these types interaction setups nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: SEQ24 MIDI sequencer]

I broadened my search from loopers and samplers to include sequencers, and found the interface I remembered (top left in the picture).